# Sprites do not behave as it supossed

Tags: pygame

I have a problem I'm stuck now for last two days. In file game_function in nested loop I'm creating aliens, when I added randint to create random numbers of aliens in a row I run in to problem. Not always (just re-run the game) but sometimes when I detect sprite edge as a method of Alien class Aliens/sprites won't change the direction, follow x axis to the right and constantly dropping down Aliens each pass of check edge. I don't know what the heck is that. Before when I haven't been using randit to generate random numbers of aliens in a row, everything was just fine.

settings.py

```
class Settings():
"""A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion"""
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game settings"""
    #Screen settings
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
    #ship settings 
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
    #Bullet settings
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_height = 15
    self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
    self.bullets_allowed = 3
    # Alien settings
    self.alien_speed_factor = 1
    self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
    # fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
    self.fleet_direction = 1
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():

def __init__(self,ai_settings, screen):
    """Initialize the ship and sets the starting position."""
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    #load the ship image and get its rect
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    #Movement Flag
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False


def update(self):
    """Update the ship's position based on the movement Flag."""
    #Update the ship's center value, not the rect
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor


    #update rect object from self.center
    self.rect.centerx = self.center


def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location"""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

In a function create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens) is nested loop, when instead of generating random number between 3-9 and then placing new instance in row I've used constant calculation which always gives 9 aliens in row everything runned just fine. Aliens changed everytime directions and just one time dropped down until next check_edge event passed the condition. So from one wall to another. Now when the randint is in place, NOT ALWAYS, when check_edge method confirms true, then call to function change_fleet_direction() is made and there I see problem, it just sometimes doesn't change the direction. where for direction is used just simple +1 or -1 and in calling for update in Alien class it should either decrease x axis or increase until edge event.

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from random import randint


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens."""
    #Create an Alien and find the number of aliens in a row
    name= 'First unused'
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen,name)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
                                  alien.rect.height)
    # Create the fleet of aliens.
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        random_num = randint(3, number_aliens_x)
        for alien_number in range(0, random_num):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number,
                         row_number)


def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):    
    """Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x


def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    """Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen."""
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height -
                         (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows


def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    """Create alien and place it in the row"""

    name = "Alien number " + str(alien_number) + " in row " + str(row_number)        
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen, name)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)



def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to key presses"""                     
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()


def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
        if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
            bullets.add(new_bullet)


def check_keyup_events(event,ship):
    """Respond to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypress and mouse events"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)


def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()


def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()
    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)    


def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
        """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                print(alien.name)
                change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
                break


def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    """Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
    print("old direction " + str(ai_settings.fleet_direction))
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
        if ai_settings.fleet_direction == 1:
            ai_settings.fleet_direction = -1
        else:
            ai_settings.fleet_direction = 1

    print("new direction" + str(ai_settings.fleet_direction))


def update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens):
    """
    Check if the fleet is at an edge,
    and then update the positions of all aliens in the fleet.
    """
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()
```

Main file alien_invasion.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf


def run_game():
# Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings,screen)
    #Make a group to store bullets in
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()

    #Create the fleet of aliens
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens)                
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

run_game()
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Bullet(Sprite):
"""A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """create a bullet object at the ship's current position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        #Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, 
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        #Store the bullet position as a decimal value.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        """Move bullet up the scereen"""
        #Update the decimal position of the bullet
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        #Update the rect position 
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
"""A class to represent a single alien in the fleet"""
def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, name):
    """Initialize the alien and set its starting position"""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings

    #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #Start each alien near the top left of the screen
    self.rect.x = self.rect.width
    self.rect.y = self.rect.height

    #Store the alien's exact position
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    self.name = name

#     def blitme(self):
#         """Draw the alien at its current location."""
#         self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
#             

def check_edges(self):
    """Return True if alien is at edge of screen."""
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
        print("Right >= right screen" +' direction is' + str(self.ai_settings.fleet_direction))
        return True
    elif self.rect.left <= 0:
        print("Left <= left")
        return True


def update(self):
    """Move the alien right or left."""
    self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor *
        self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

I'm new to pygame and sprites, I don't understand it why randit has such impact. I've placed in the code when crucial changes are about to be made print statements to debug it from console (but I dunno if it is logic problem). Anyone who can shed a light to it I would appreciate so much. Lost 2 days of learning and programming already. Running python 3.4 from Eclipse Neon on win 10 Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Found the mistake, indentation in func change_fleet_direction(), if block: cannot be in for loop.